# Chromium browser developer tool "search as you type" option setting is constant

Tags: chromium, configuration-managment

Why is the Chromium browser developer tool "search as you type" option in the settings cannot be saved, so it will always be back to default of being set after unsetting it?

Comment: why would anyone here know what the developers are thinking? ... perhaps a better question is `how to save the setting?`